# need of vblank in Display subssytem

Tags: android, linux-kernel, vsync

I am not clear on the use of the **vertical blank** (**vblank**) on display panels.

Could some one please explain

- Significance of **vblank** ?
- How it can be utilized in the display subsystem?

Comment: Why have you tagged your question **android** and **linux-kernel**?  The **vblank** is a slice of time when the display memory (frame buffer) is not being transferred to a display.  Sometimes, *tearing* will result if you update the memory while the display hardware DMA's the video memory.  Often there is a *vblank* interrupt and you can use this to flush a cache or switch the frame buffer base to seamlessly change the image.  You need to give more specifics on the hardware to say how it can be used.

Answer (score 5):

### Vertical Blanking Interval

A legacy from the olden days of Cathode Ray Tube (CRT) displays.

> The vertical blanking interval (VBI) is a very brief period of time during some video signals through which transmission of visual field/frame information is temporarily suspended. This interval corresponds to the time that was required for the electron guns of old CRT display technologies to move their beam's position back up to the left side of the first line of the television/display screen in order to begin to trace out the next screen field. Though this requirement is no longer relevant to modern digital display technologies, the VBI itself has been retained in video signals for compatibility purposes.

As nothing is displayed onscreen during the VBI, this portion of the video signal can be used for the purposes of carrying other data information. Indeed, various test signals, Closed Captioning, Teletext, copy-protection mechanisms, and various forms of digital data all exploit the opportunity afforded by the VBI.

In current generation digital display systems, VBI time-period ( **VSYNC** or **VBLANK** interrupt) is used to [swap display buffers](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Swap_Interval) when using [double or triple buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering). This way one can completely avoid onscreen [tearing artifacts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing).